# Mysql database best practices

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

What is the mysql database best practices for multiple users?

When build a SAAS cloud projects are you best to have a new database for all users or put a users data in their own table or just put it all in the same database and use primary key to find a users data?

What are the pro's and con's?

Comment: yes,no,maybe pick one(or more)

Comment: Want to know what people think is best practices and also the pro's and con's of them all.

Comment: to broad "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." each one of your suggestions is best practice under a certain circumstance

Comment: Best depends on your project design and data. Please be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: look up and to to right. there is a white box labeled "search"

Answer (score 2):

I NEVER create per-used tables. If the logical meaning of the data is the same, then they should share a table. I also never allow automatic creation of tables - creation of tables is done by a DBA, by hand (sometimes by running a program or a script, but always initiated by a human being.

I also have a hard-and-fast rule to have static SQL (using bound parameters for values only). This lets me keep tight control of what is read from/written to the database, and where - very important to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: disagree, i have a system with per user db's and auto-created db's. Unless you know the exact scope of the project, you cant make such assumptions